# Gnome Software Center Stuck Installing Updates

Tags: updates, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04, gnome-software

I always install software updates from terminal via `sudo apt update` && `sudo apt dist-upgrade` but today, I was browsing the Gnome Software and I saw OS Updates in the Updates tab. So I clicked install, but it never asked me for my password. The progress bar went to 50% and got stuck there for over 20 minutes. The update was very small in size. Maybe it is stuck because it can't authenticate dpkg because it doesn't have my password. Now what should I do to resume the installation? I am using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. It is stuck there forever!

PS: The packages are not from the universe or multiverse repository. In the similar question the update got stuck because it was installing from those two repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just restart. It worked for me.

Alternatively, you can bring up the `gnome-system-monitor` and kill the `gnome-software` process and then restart the update procedure again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your out of memory or It can be a system problem  , I had the same problem and it work changing from the Software and updates application  and go to the first tab and change your server to main server (yours might be in United states server )